# How to create and use array of type extensions in Fortran?

Tags: oop, fortran

I have an abstract base class.  I make two extensions of the base class.  I want to store all of the objects made from either of the extended classes in a single array.  I believe I'm able to do this by making an array of pointers that point to the base class; I can populate such an array with any extension of the base class.  However, when I try to call a procedure of the extended class object, the compiler complains that the procedure is not in the base class.  I figured the code would know that the pointer is pointing to an extension, and look at its type bound procedures, but apparently I'm wrong.

An example is shown below.  I have two questions: What would I need to do to fix this, and is this a radically incorrect way to approach the problem I'm trying to solve?

```
module thetype

   implicit none

   type, abstract :: base
      integer :: ival
   end type base

   type, extends(base) :: extend1
      real :: val
      contains
         procedure :: Init=>Init_extend1
         procedure :: Print=>Print_extend1
   end type extend1

   type, extends(base) :: extend2
      character(len=1) :: chr
      contains
         procedure :: Init=>Init_extend2
         procedure :: Print=>Print_extend2
   end type extend2

   type :: ptr
      class(base), pointer :: ptrobj
   end type

contains

   subroutine Init_extend1(me,ival,val)
      class(extend1), intent(in out) :: me
      integer, intent(in) :: ival
      real, intent(in) :: val
      me%ival=ival
      me%val=val
   end subroutine Init_extend1

   subroutine Print_extend1(me,id)
      class(extend1), intent(in) :: me
      integer, intent(in) :: id
      print *, "Extend1 obj:", id
      print *, me%ival
      print *, me%val
   end subroutine Print_extend1

   subroutine Init_extend2(me,ival,chr)
      class(extend2), intent(in out) :: me
      integer, intent(in) :: ival
      character(len=1), intent(in) :: chr
      me%ival=ival
      me%chr=chr
   end subroutine Init_extend2

   subroutine Print_extend2(me,id)
      class(extend2), intent(in) :: me
      integer, intent(in) :: id
      print *, "Extend2 obj:", id
      print *, me%ival
      print *, me%chr
   end subroutine Print_extend2
end module thetype

program main
   use thetype
   implicit none

   type(extend1), target, allocatable :: extend1_obj(:)
   type(extend2), target, allocatable :: extend2_obj(:)
   type(ptr), allocatable :: ptrs(:)
   integer :: i

   allocate(extend1_obj(1))
   allocate(extend2_obj(2))
   allocate(ptrs(3))

   call extend1_obj(1)%Init(1,2.0)

   call extend2_obj(1)%Init(3,'a')
   call extend2_obj(2)%Init(3,'b')

   ptrs(1)%ptrobj=>extend1_obj(1)
   ptrs(2)%ptrobj=>extend2_obj(1)
   ptrs(3)%ptrobj=>extend2_obj(2)

   do i=1,size(ptrs,1)
      call ptrs(i)%ptrobj%Print(i)
   end do

end program main
```

Comment: You need to declare the procedures in the base class (this is what the compiler is telling you) and you ought to give them the `deferred` attribute.  I don't have the time or wit to explain fully but https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n2a2.htm is a good place to start reading about all this.

Comment: This question is much clearer than the original duplicate.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I guess my question is more philosophical in nature.  This requirement forces me to make the argument list of all Init procedures that extend the base class (ival,val,chr).  However, 'extend1' doesn't need the chr value and 'extend2' doesn't need 'val'.  This forces my Init procedures to pass in un-needed data, which just seems wrong.  I guess I'm failing to see the value of an abstract type if all type extension procedures need to be declared as deferred in the base class and the argument list set in stone.  It doesn't sound very extensible.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I think I misunderstood you at first.  I thought I had to mark the 'Init' procedure deferred.  I was wrong.  I had to mark 'Print' as deferred since I don't have a 'select type' construct in the do loop.  Therefore, the interface of all 'Print' procedures must be identical, which makes perfect sense.  I can make the Init procedures to have any interface I desire as long as I don't try to initialize the extensions inside of a one-size-fits-all loop.